# Dynamically display selected item as an alert when drop down list item changes(Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, select, drop-down-menu, dynamically-generated

I am trying to change the values displayed within a division everytime a selected dropdown list item changes. Performing this on a button click is what I've been doing so far, but, I would like to know if this value can be automatically changed with every selection change.

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <option value="st1" selected="selected">Create new Stream</option>
    <option value="st1">Stream 1</option>
    <option value="st2">Stream 2</option>
    <option value="st3">Stream 3</option>
    <option value="st4">Stream 4</option>
</select>

<input type="button" value="show attributes" class="panel-button-attr" onclick="choice()">
```

My js function:

```
function choice() {

    var choice=document.getElementById("mySelect");
    var strUser = choice.options[choice.selectedIndex].text;

    if(strUser=="Stream 1"){
        alert("You selected Stream 1");
    }
    else if(strUser=="Stream 2"){
        alert("You selected Stream 2");
    }
    else if(strUser=="Stream 3"){
        alert("You selected Stream 3");
    }
    else if(strUser=="Stream 4"){
        alert("You selected Stream 4");
    }
    else {
        alert("Create Stream");
    }

}
```

According to this code, I need to display the alert message without calling the choice(0 function everytime. Instead it should be alerted with every selection change in the drop down list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the onchange event on the select:

```
<select id="mySelect" onchange="choice()">
    <option value="st1" selected="selected">Create new Stream</option>
    <option value="st1">Stream 1</option>
    <option value="st2">Stream 2</option>
    <option value="st3">Stream 3</option>
    <option value="st4">Stream 4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can do this (more dynamic):

```
var choice  = document.getElementById("mySelect");

function choice()
{
    var strUser = choice.options[choice.selectedIndex].text;

    if(strUser !== "Create new Stream"){
        alert("Create new stream");
    }
    else{
        alert("You selected " + strUser);
    }
}
```

Then, you have to add a "onChange" event to your select.

```
<select id="mySelect" onchange="choice()">
    <option value="st1" selected="selected">Create new Stream</option>
    <option value="st1">Stream 1</option>
    <option value="st2">Stream 2</option>
    <option value="st3">Stream 3</option>
    <option value="st4">Stream 4</option>
</select>
```

It's not clean at all, but it will work.
If you want a better and proper way to do it, let me know.